# probability-combinatorics problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations, combinations

I am having trouble with a specific type of combinatorics problem, so if you could please explain it in detail like you are explaining it to a 5 year old I would be grateful.

For example: $n$ persons threw their hats in the box. Box is shaken so that probability of picking each hat is the same. Find the probability that exactly $k$ persons will get their own hat.

I think you can see what type of problem I am struggling with, it is where both objects are different(in this example it was that we had $n$ different people and $n$ different hats, it could be $n$ different balls and $n$ different boxes etc.)

In the solution they use generalized form of theorem that says 
$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$ 
Now, I understand what this theorem means, but not really how it is applied.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, after the box is shaken, people **each** take **one** hat out of the box.  Any way of taking the hats out of the box can be described as a *permutation* (*consider each person as having a number on their shirt and on their hat numbered $1$ through $n$, have the persons stand in a row after getting their hat according to the number on their shirt.  The numbers as read on the hats is our permutation*).  Each permutation is stated in the problem to be equally likely to occur.

Before worrying about probability, let us first *count* in how many ways this can be done.

For exactly $k$ people to get their correct hat back out of the box, that means that the remaining $n-k$ people got a different hat than they started.  If we were to ignore the $k$ people who did get their correct hat for now, we count how many ways the $n-k$ people could have their hats shuffled around so that none of them got their correct hat back.  This is what is referred to as a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

The number of derangements on $n-k$ elements is notated as $!(n-k)$ and can be found to be equal to

> $$!(n-k)=(n-k)!\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

As alluded to in your post, how this formula is come to is as a result of the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_{n-k}$ be the events where $A_i$ is the event that person $i$ did get their own personal hat back.  We have then $!(n-k)=|\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n-k} A_i^c|$ which by De'Morgans can be rewritten as $=|S_{n-k}|-|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n-k}A_i|$ which by inclusion-exclusion expands further as $=|S_{n-k}|-|A_1|-|A_2|-\dots-|A_{n-k}|+|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+\dots - |A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|-\dots \pm |A_1\cap\dots\cap A_{n-k}|$

Each term in the above expansion can be calculated, for example $|A_1\cap A_2|$ is the number of permutations where both $1$ and $2$ are fixed points.  Approaching by multiplication principle, we just need to choose how to arrange the remaining $(n-k-2)$ numbers which can be done in $(n-k-2)!$ ways.  Taking into account the number of each type of term which occurs, there are $\binom{n-k}{1}$ terms with only a single event appearing, there are $\binom{n-k}{2}$ terms with two events intersected appearing, there are $\binom{n-k}{3}$ terms with three events intersected appearing, etc... we can make the algebraic simplifications necessary to arrive at the formula highlighted above.

---

As for your specific problem, again, for exactly $k$ people to get their correct hat back, that means that we choose which $k$ people those are and then choose a derangement of the remaining $n-k$ hats.  There are $\binom{n}{k}\cdot !(n-k)$ such ways for this to happen.  Converting this to a probability then, we divide by the number of elements in our sample space, which is $n!$ to get the probability that exactly $k$ people get their correct hat back as being $$\binom{n}{k}\cdot \frac{!(n-k)}{n!}$$

Comment: is the problem harder if the box is stirred mr Bond?